# Apache on windows service on port 80 becomes unavailable when a reverse proxy is activated

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, mapserver

I have an apache server running on a windows system on port 80 with a Mapserver service (configured by ms4w). Service is running fine in FCGI.
I also have some web applications running on the same machine on other ports. I managed to successfully run these web applications via reverse proxy on apache using virtual hosts and i now can access them without using port number in URL.
My problem is that when httpd.conf is modified to enable reverse proxy and after apache server is restarted mapserver doesn't work anymore on port 80 and it returns a 503 error (service unavailable).

I enabled proxy_module, proxy_http_module and proxy_fcgi-module. I also tried to set virtual host for mapserver itself, without success.
Is there any configuration I'm missing to get Mapserver work

Comment: Two separate programs can not listen on port 80 at the same time. Put Mapserver on a different port and use the reverse proxy to proxy to that port.